# Custom Event isn't be tracked by using applicationInsight within vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, azure-application-insights

I am using azure application-insight to track events of a self-built search engine written within VUE.

I wrapped the application-insight SDK as a service and export a function.

```js
import {
  ApplicationInsights
} from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web'

const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: {
    instrumentationKey: "xxxx",
    autoTrackPageVisitTime: true,
    enableAutoRouteTracking: true,
    enableRequestHeaderTracking: true,
    enableResponseHeaderTracking: true
  }
})

appInsights.loadAppInsights();
appInsights.trackEvent();

export function useAppInsights() {
  return appInsights
}
```

Then in my search-view page (search.vue), I call the service of application-insight and register two custom events to track.

```html
`
<script>
  import {
    useAppInsights
  } from '../services/AppInsights'

  useAppInsights().trackEvent("search page loaded!");
  useAppInsights().trackPageView({
    name: 'search page'
  });

  export default {
    methods: {
      addQuery(key) {
        useAppInsights().trackEvent({
          name: 'SelectTag',
          properties: {
            searchInput: key
          }
        });
        this.searchInput = key;
        this.handleSearch();
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

The search.vue is integrated into the main.js using the router.

```js
import Search from './components/Search.vue'
import Product from './components/Product.vue'

const routers = [{
    path: '/search',
    name: 'Search',
    component: Search
  },
  {
    path: '/product',
    name: 'Product',
    component: Product
  },
]
export default routers
```

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import "element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/base.css";
import routers from "./router";
import ElementUI from "element-ui";
import "element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css";
import App from "./App.vue";
import axios from "axios";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(ElementUI);
Vue.use(axios);

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: routers,
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
});
```

The catalogue of my project is

[image]

But in my azure application-insight portal, I cannot see any events at all.
[image]

Does anyone have solutions to this condition? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I referred the following articles to realize trackevent codes:

- https://dev.to/ardc_overflow/monitorando-uma-aplicacao-vuejs-com-o-application-insights-9h1
- https://github.com/microsoft/applicationinsights-js#npm-setup-ignore-if-using-snippet-setup

In the second article, the sample of event tracking using application-insight is very clear:

```js
appInsights.trackEvent({
  name: 'some event',
  properties: { // accepts any type
    prop1: 'string',
    prop2: 123.45,
    prop3: {
      nested: 'objects are okay too'
    }
  }
});
```

emmm...so I am trapped by the condition.

Comment: Hi, this problem is resolved just know. The reason is when I created the application insight resource, I choose the workspace mode rather than the classic one. But I have no corresponding workspace for the resource but an empty one. That's why my app did send tracked requests to ai, but ai doesn't show them.

Comment: so, can you explain me what are the changes we need to make in order to work with VueJs ?